# How to remove a specific key from JSON response coming from MongoDB in ExpressJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm creating a simple application using `MEAN` stack. My code is working fine but i want to remove one key from the response. Please look at my ocde.

**models/user.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const userSchema = new Schema({
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String,
    email: String,
    //password: String, // <--------- commented out
    userid: String,
    skills: []
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('user', userSchema, 'users');
```

Notice that I've commented out `password` key. But I guess that's not enough. As I can still see password in response:

**Postman screenshot**

**(Note: Email Id and encrypted Password in this image are absolutely fake and hence there's no security issue)**

[image]

**api.js**

```
const User = require('../models/user');
...
router.get('/users', function (req, res) {
    console.log('Get request for all users');
    User.find({})
        .exec(function (err, user) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("Error retrieving users");
            } else {
                res.json(user);
            }
        });
});
```

Now tomorrow When I'll be using real email and password, though I'll encrypt the password but still i don't want to show `password` key whatsoever. It should not be displayed in the network tab of browser also.

Please give me some directions.

Comment: No need to mark the password as a comment. I provided the solution for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the mongoose `select` method to exclude certain fields. https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-select

```js
User.find({})
        .select('-password')
        .exec(function (err, user) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("Error retrieving users");
            } else {
                res.json(user);
            }
        });
```

Comment: This worked. Can you explain little bit whats happening in `.select('-password')`. Why there is a hyphen. I read the doc you shared but this thing is not very clear.

Comment: From the documentation I linked:
> When using string syntax, prefixing a path with - will flag that path as excluded. When a path does not have the - prefix, it is included. Lastly, if a path is prefixed with +, it forces inclusion of the path, which is useful for paths excluded at the schema level.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```js
const User = require('../models/user');
...
router.get('/users', function (req, res) {
    console.log('Get request for all users');
    const user = User.find({} , {password:0});

    return res.json({ user: user });
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 0):

If you just do not want to show the password while outputting the data then you just need to do this in your schema:

```
const MongooseSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  firstName: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Please enter a first name!'],
  },
  lastName: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Please enter a last name!'],
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: [true, 'Please enter an email address!'],
    match: [
      /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/,
      'Please enter a valid email address',
    ],
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Please enter a password'],
    select: false,
  },
  // userid: String, Id for user will be created by mongodb automatically
  skills: {
    type: Array,
    required: [true, 'Please enter skills!'],
  },
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', MongooseSchema);
```

Now when you will find users or a user, a password or passwords will not be returned in the response. I improved your schema too.